# Differentiate between endpoint with query param vs without query param in Spring Boot RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I differentiate between an endpoint with query param vs an endpoint without query param in a rest controller? The below mapping throws this error -

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot
> map 'itemController' method

```
@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<Item> getAllItems(){
    return menuService.getAllItems();
}


@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<Item> getAllItems(@RequestParam("itemtype") ItemType itemType){
    return menuService.findItemsByItemType(itemType);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the parameter optional:

```java
@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<Item> getAllItems(@RequestParam(name = "itemtype", required = false) ItemType itemType){
    if (itemType == null)
        return menuService.getAllItems();
    return menuService.findItemsByItemType(itemType);
}
```